# my app stops when try to go back to my previous activity

Tags: java, android

**My Code:**

```
 userListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String userURL = "https://api.github.com/users/" + userNameList.get(position) + "?" + accessToken;
        new JSONTask().execute(userURL);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProfileActivity.class);
        String key = userNameList.get(position);
        intent.putExtra("userName", key);

        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

This part of my code is a click listener of each item in my list view which is a profile of github users. So, whenever I click an item, it moves to another activity which parses the info from the DB which were stored through

```
new JSONTask().execute(userURL);
```

The **JSONTask** (asyncTask). Moving to the next activity works fine, but when I press the back button, it suddenly stops my app.

It doesn't give me an error when I comment out the JSONTask, but then it won't store the info of the user to the DB.

What could be the problem in this case?

Comment: you probably be calling `getContentResolver` or using db inctance which is no longer aviable 'cuz your activity is no longer alive , hence the crash

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh Basically, when I call JSONTask, it parses the JSON from the API and stores it into a Firebase DB. In the next Activity, I fetch the data from the DB based on the passed-in "userName". Would that probably be the reason?

Comment: simply don't let your thread to anything with references in activity when it dies , google `weakrefernce`

Comment: So, what would be a solution to this?

Comment: i already have suggested some solution , google them or i would suggest post the whole code with logcat details , your question go for re-opening again , or if it takes too long , delete it re post it